# Why doesn't groovy withTransaction rollback on SqlException?

Tags: mysql, groovy, transactions

Using the following

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventDb", "user",
        "pwd", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

def sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO GTEST (EVENTID,TSTAMP,USER_ID,USER_FIRST_NAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
def sqlParams = ['EVENTID':0, 'TSTAMP':'','USER_ID':'janew','USER_FIRST_NAME':'janewithaverylongnamesothatitdoesntfitwell']
sqlParams['TSTAMP'] = new Date()

sql.withTransaction {stmt ->
    def eventId = sql.executeInsert("INSERT INTO EVENTS (LOGID,TSTAMP) VALUES (2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
    sqlParams['EVENTID'] = eventId [0][0]
    sql.executeInsert(sqlInsert, sqlParams.values().toList())
}
```

The second execute will fail, however the first insert does not roll back.  What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not showing the definition of the tables; maybe those are MyISAM, and therefore do not support transactions?

Comment: Thanks!  GTest was innoDB however Events table was indeed MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16863373/1216686

Not an exact match to your example but there may be something in there for you or someone else.  I know this is an old post but it seems to be a common problem among Groovy Sql object users.